# Polymer error "Undefined is not a function" and blank page

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I'm trying to get started with Polymer, but when i put the *webcomponents.js* in my *index.html* i got a blank page. If i add an import i got an error `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"` in `Polymer.html:37`.

This is my *index.html*:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Atom Shell App</title>

    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/font-roboto/roboto.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-media-query/core-media-query.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">

    <!-- build:css public/css/master.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/css/main.css">
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </head>
  <body unresolved>
    <core-toolbar style="background: #4285f4;">
      <paper-icon-button icon="menu"></paper-icon-button>
      <span flex>Title</span>
      <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert"></paper-icon-button>
    </core-toolbar>

    <!-- build:js public/js/master.js -->
    <script src="public/js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain your error is originating from "public/js/main.js". Please provide the snippet where you create an instance of `Polymer`.

Comment: *main.js* is empty. I didn't know i should instantiate Polymer with Javascript before use it. I just copied the code from https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-elements/demos/core-toolbar.html

Comment: Ah, I see you are using the `core-toolbar` element, perhaps you need to import it as well? `<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">`

Comment: I forgot to add it to the snippet. I added the imports, now i got 8 ```undefined is not a function``` errors and ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'registerElement' on 'Document': Registration failed for type 'undefined'. The type name is invalid.```.

Comment: Are there any script references mentioned in these errors?